# Setting up USB-serial Receipt Printer (epson tm-t88ii/iii compatible) on Debian Wheezy

Tags: printing, debian, usbserial, epson, receipt

I'm trying to get my receipt printer working on Debian Wheezy.

On being plugged into computer, my USB-serial Receipt Printer (epson tm-t88ii/ii compatible) tics question marks every few seconds, and does not respond to commands.

the output from the printer is:

```
˥ ?????????????????£???≡█
```

attempting to print to it by echo fails with error:

```
/dev/ttyUSB0: Permission denied
```

even as root.

attempting to open the cash drawer fails with error:

```
/dev/ttyUSB0: No such device
```

How do I get it to stop the tic and print?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I got it working:

after sending:

```
# echo "test" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

returns Permission denied,

```
# dmesg | tail
```

returns:

```
[92780.658576] ftdi_sio 2-3:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[92780.658624] usb 2-3: Detected FT232BM
[92780.658626] usb 2-3: Number of endpoints 2
[92780.658628] usb 2-3: Endpoint 1 MaxPacketSize 64
[92780.658630] usb 2-3: Endpoint 2 MaxPacketSize 64
[92780.658632] usb 2-3: Setting MaxPacketSize 64
[92780.664556] usb 2-3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[92782.102904] usb 2-3: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ftdi_sio while 'brltty' sets config #1
[92782.104874] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[92782.104891] ftdi_sio 2-3:1.0: device disconnected
```

This indicates there is a conflict with package 'brltty', (braille device), which is installed by default.

```
# apt-get remove brltty
```

stops the tic

set baud with

```
# stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600
```

try echo

```
$ echo "test" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

it prints!

What about the cash drawer?

```
$ echo -e "\033\0160\0\031\372" >> /dev/ttyUSB0
```

it opens!

Problem solved. Unless you need a braille display as well.

Comment: I found that with the TM-T88II and a Profilic PL2303 one needs a stty setting of `38400 8N1`. Just leaving that here.

Comment: This was ver helpful, how did you get the code to open the drawer from the command line? I am looking to feed and cut the paper with this method.